# Is there a "Set" data structure in .Net?

Tags: c#, data-structures, set

Ideally, I'm looking for a templated logical Set class.  It would have all of the standard set operations such as Union, Intersection, Etc., and collapse duplicated items.

I ended up creating my own set class based on the C# Dictionary<>- just using the Keys.

Comment: @d03boy: Well it has HashSet<T> now, but after using it a bit I think the interface really sucks.

Comment: .NET 4 has an ISet interface along with two implementations, HashSet and SortedSet

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688779/set-class-with-mathematical-set-equality-by-default) for a simple implementation of a set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Set collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183685/c-sharp-set-collection)

Answer (score 52):

[`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) is about the closest you'll get, I think.

Comment: Matt, +1. That sounds like exactly what he asked for. Looks like that was added long after the codeproject article was written.

Answer (score 15):

The best set implementation I have seen is part of the wonderful Wintellect's Power Collections:
http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections.

The set implementation can be found here:
http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections/SourceControl/FileView.aspx?itemId=101886&changeSetId=6259
It has all the expected set operations (union, intersect, etc).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 10):

No, there is not one natively in the framework.  There is an open source implementation that most projects use, (i.e. nHibernate) called Iesi.Collections.  Here's a CodeProject article about it:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sets.aspx

Answer (score 10):

Have you checked out the [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397727.aspx) in 3.5?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think c# has anything built in, but I know there are a couple of implementations floating around on the net. There are also some good articles around on this sort of thing:

[This is part 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379575(VS.80).aspx) of a series on efficiently representing data structure. This part focuses on representing sets in C#.

[An implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/collections/SetCollectionsForCSharp.aspx) of a set collection 
[An implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Types_Set.aspx) of a set class
[Yet another implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/yaset.aspx) of a set class

And finally...

I've actually used [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sets.aspx) myself as the basis of a set implementation that I did a year or so ago.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
public sealed class MathSet<T> : HashSet<T>, IEquatable<MathSet<T>>
{
    public override int GetHashCode() => this.Select(elt => elt.GetHashCode()).Sum().GetHashCode();

    public bool Equals(MathSet<T> obj) => SetEquals(obj);

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as MathSet<T>);

    public static bool operator ==(MathSet<T> a, MathSet<T> b) =>
        ReferenceEquals(a, null) ? ReferenceEquals(b, null) : a.Equals(b);

    public static bool operator !=(MathSet<T> a, MathSet<T> b) => !(a == b);
}
```

Example usage:

```
var a = new MathSet<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var b = new MathSet<int> { 3, 2, 1 };

var c = a.Equals(b);                        // true

var d = new MathSet<MathSet<int>> { a, b }; // contains one element

var e = a == b;                             // true
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688779/set-class-with-mathematical-set-equality-by-default) for why this approach was considered over `HashSet`.