# C# Set collection?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, set

Does anyone know if there is a good equivalent to Java's `Set` collection in C#? I know that you can somewhat mimic a set using a `Dictionary` or a `HashTable` by populating but ignoring the values, but that's not a very elegant way.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Try [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

> The HashSet(Of T) class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order...
>
> The capacity of a HashSet(Of T) object is the number of elements that the object can hold. A HashSet(Of T) object's capacity automatically increases as elements are added to the object.
>
> The HashSet(Of T) class is based on the model of mathematical sets and provides high-performance set operations similar to accessing the keys of the [Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) or [Hashtable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) collections. In simple terms, the HashSet(Of T) class can be thought of as a [Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) collection without values.
>
> A HashSet(Of T) collection is not sorted and cannot contain duplicate elements...

Comment: Unfortunately, HashSets weren't added until just recently.  If you're working in an older version of the framework, you're going to have to stick with your munged Dictionary<> or Hashtable.

Answer (score 449):

If you're using .NET 3.5, you can use [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). It's true that .NET doesn't cater for sets as well as Java does though.

The [Wintellect PowerCollections](https://github.com/timdetering/Wintellect.PowerCollections) may help too.

Comment: does anyone know why it's called HashSet and not just Set?

Comment: I suspect that Set is a keyword in some languages, which could cause issues.

Comment: `set` is also a keyword in C#

Comment: @Manish: No it's not. See section 2.4.3 of the C# 3 spec. It only has special meaning for properties.

Comment: @Jon

Thanks for the enlightenment. I always thought it was a keyword. Downloaded the C# 3 spec.

Comment: The reason for calling it HashSet, instead of just Set, is the same as in Java- "Set" describes an interface, whereas "HashSet" describes an implementation- specifically, this is a Set backed by a Hash Map. In this way, we know (or should strongly expect) that insert and access should take O(1) access time, vs a "LinkedListSet" which would lead us to expect insert and access to take O(n) time.

Comment: what do you mean ".NET doesn't cater for sets as well as Java does though."? Is this Set somehow imperfect compared to Java's ?

Comment: @Louis: Which Set are you talking about? Java has *lots* of different implementations of Set for various situations. .NET had one in .NET 3.5 (HashSet) and two in .NET 4 (HashSet and SortedSet). The fact that we had to wait until .NET 3.5 to start with is pretty surprising.

Answer (score 36):

**If you're using .NET 4.0 or later:**

In the case where you need sorting then use [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx). Otherwise if you don't, then use [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) since it's `O(1)` for search and manipulate operations. Whereas `SortedSet<T>` is `O(log n)` for search and manipulate operations.

Answer (score 16):

I use Iesi.Collections http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sets.aspx

It's used in lot of OSS projects, I first came across it in NHibernate

Answer (score 13):

I use a wrapper around a `Dictionary<T, object>`, storing nulls in the values. This gives O(1) add, lookup and remove on the keys, and to all intents and purposes acts like a set.

Comment: You must mean it's roughly equivalent to std::unordered_set. std::set is ordered. For example, you can quickly find the start and end point of a range and iterate from the start to the end, visiting items in key-order. SortedDictionary *is* roughly equivalent to std::set.

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at [Power Collections](https://github.com/timdetering/Wintellect.PowerCollections). Apart from `Set` and `OrderedSet` it has a few other usefull collection types such as `Deque, MultiDictionary, Bag, OrderedBag, OrderedDictionary` and `OrderedMultiDictionary`.

For more collections, there is also the [C5 Generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/).

Answer (score -8):

I know this is an old thread, but I was running into the same problem and found HashSet to be very unreliable because given the same seed, GetHashCode() returned different codes.  So, I thought, why not just use a List and hide the add method like this

```
public class UniqueList<T> : List<T>
{
    public new void Add(T obj)
    {
        if(!Contains(obj))
        {
            base.Add(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Because List uses the Equals method solely to determine equality, you can define the Equals method on your T type to make sure you get the desired results.

Comment: The reason you wouldn't want to use this is because `List.Contains` is of `O(n)` complexity which means that your `Add` method now becomes `O(n)` complexity as well. Assuming the inner collection doesn't need to be resized, `Add` for both `List` and `HashMap` should be of `O(1)` complexity.

TLDR: This will work, but it's hacky and less efficient.

Comment: Sure, if your objects don't return an appropriate value for GetHashCode, you should not put them into a hash-based container.  It would be better to fix GetHashCode than to use a less efficient container.