# What is the best collection type to easily lookup values with multiple, identical keys?

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

I have **text** documents like the following which contain **single** and **multiple** variables:

```
title:: Report #3
description:: This is the description.
note:: more information is available from marketing
note:: time limit for this project is 18 hours
todo:: expand the outline
todo:: work on the introduction
todo:: lookup footnotes
```

I need to iterate through the lines of this text document and fill a **collection** with these variables, currently I'm using a **Dictionary**:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> VariableNamesAndValues { get; set; }
```

But this doesn't work on **multiple**, **identical** keys such as "note" and "todo" in the above example since keys have to be **unique** in a Dictionary.

**What is the best collection so that I can not only get single values like this:**

```
string variableValue = "";
if (VariableNamesAndValues.TryGetValue("title", out variableValue))
    return variableValue;
else
    return "";
```

**but that I can also get multiple values out like this:**

```
//PSEUDO-CODE:
List<string> variableValues = new List<string>();
if (VariableNamesAndValues.TryGetValues("note", out variableValues))
    return variableValues;
else
    return null;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your keys and values are strings then use a [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx). It supports multiple values for a given key.

It's not the most efficient collection in the world. Particularly because it's a non-generic class, uses a lot of virtual method calls, and the GetValues method will allocate arrays for its return values. But unless you require the best *performing* collection, this is certainly the most *convenient* collection that does what you ask.

Comment: But you have to manually split the values when you retrieve them. I would recommend this be wrapped into its own little class.

Comment: No that is not true. There is a GetValues method.

Comment: Man don't you love that feeling of embarrassment?

Comment: It's understandable. NameValueCollection is strange in a lot of ways. It doesn't implement IDictionary for example.

Comment: I bet the performance issues with this collection are negated by the workarounds you have to use in the other solutions.

Comment: Maybe, but not necessarily. Particularly if you read more than you write to the collection, the arrays created by the GetValues method could be a problem. Internally I think it's just splitting the string.

Comment: thanks, this is what I ended up using: http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=362

Answer (score 3):

You can make a Dictionary of **key:** string and **value:** List of String

`Dictionary<string,List<string>>`

**EDIT 1 & 2:**
I've thought of a better solution if you can use .NET 3.0 or higher.
Here's a LINQ example (I typed it without Visual Studio, so I hope it compiles ;)):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("content.txt");
string[] separator = {":: "};
var splitOptions = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries;

var items = from line in lines
            let parts = line.Split(separator, splitOptions)
            group parts by parts[0] into partGroups
            select partGroups;
```

A short explanation of the example above:

- Get all lines from the file in a String array
- Define some Split options (to keep the example readable)
- For each line in the lines array, split it on the ":: "
- Group the results of the split on the first split part (e.g. title, description, note, ...)
- Store the grouped items in the items variable

The result of the LINQ query is a `IQueryable<IGrouping<string, IEnumberable<string>>>`.
Each item in the result has a `Key` property containing the key of the line (title, description, note, ...).
Each item can be enumerated containing all of values.

Comment: this is definitely a solution but I will be doing a lot of the managing of the collection myself, e.g. logic such as if-key-doesn't-exist-yet create-new-entry otherwise add-to-List<string>-of-existing-entry, I would think this would be a common enough need in programming that some core .NET collection type would exist to  handle it inherently so I can just say .Add(key, value) and either the single or multiple key is stored internally.

Comment: @Edward: no sorry, not that I know of. What you could do is use LINQ to process your string lines and use the ToDictionary method to create your dictionary.

Comment: @Edward: I've put some more thought into it, have a look at the new example :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` :

```
ILookup<string, string> lookup = lines.Select(line => line.Split(new string[] { ":: " })
                                      .ToLookup(arr => arr[0], arr => arr[1]);
IEnumerable<string> notes = lookup["note"];
```

Note that this collection is read-only

Comment: Ahh that's the one I was looking for too but I couldn't remember. I saw it on a Jon Skeet tweet recently.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [PowerCollections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/) which is an open source project that has a MultiDictionary data structure which solves your problem.

Here is a [sample of how to use it](http://weblogs.asp.net/esanchez/archive/2006/05/31/PowerCollections.MultiDictionary.aspx).

Note: Jon Skeet suggested it before in his answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183685/c-set-collection)

Comment: +1, I love PowerCollections. But it was designed circa .NET 2.0 and hasn't really been touched since. It could probably use a rewrite with .NET 3.5 or 4.0 in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>` for getting multiple values in the past. I would love to know if there is something better though.

Here is how you can emulate getting only one value.

```
public static bool TryGetValue(this Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> map, string key, out string result)
{
    var set = default(HashSet<string>);
    if (map.TryGetValue(key, out set))
    {
        result = set.FirstOrDefault();
        return result == default(string);
    }
    result = default(string);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @ChaosPandion +1: HashSet is a good suggestion, although it isn't that much faster than a List for small lists. And you lose the ability to get a specific item by index from the set. I often use HashSets for complex objects or large lists of value types.

Comment: @Zyphrax - Agreed, I am just remembering situations where each entry in the dictionary had to have a unique set of values. LINQ makes using the `HashSet` a little more convenient if not slower.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a c# expert, but I think `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

or some kind of `HashMap<string, List<string>>` might work.
For example (Java pseudocode):
aKey aValue
aKey anotherValue

```
if(map.get(aKey) == null)
{
   map.put(aKey, new ArrayList(){{add(aValue);}});
} 
else 
{
   map.put(aKey, map.get(aKey).add(anotherValue));
}
```

or something similar.
(or, the shortest way:

```
map.put(aKey, map.get(aKey) != null ? map.get(aKey).add(value) : new ArrayList(){{add(value);}});
```