# name of assoc-diff in C#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

What do you call this method, (is it available in .net?)

```
var list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 };
var list2 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3};
var results = list1.diff(list2);

results:
{ 2, 4 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exactly return what you want, You can refactor it in a Extension Method:

```
var results = list1.GroupBy(p => p).Select(p => new { item = p.Key, count = p.Count() })
                .Concat(list2.GroupBy(p => p).Select(p => new { item = p.Key, count = -p.Count() }))
                .GroupBy(p => p.item).Select(p => new { item = p.Key, count = p.Sum(q => q.count) })
                .Where(p => p.count > 0)
                .SelectMany(p => Enumerable.Repeat(p.item, p.count));
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing built in is the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356791.aspx) LINQ operator.

> Produces the set difference of two sequences.

Though with your example it will result in:

```
{ 4 }
```

I don't believe there is a direct analogue to what you want.

Comment: I can implement it with a dictionary <item:T,count:int>
but I'm not sure it would be as efficient.

Comment: @better-than-soil - probably.

Answer (score 2):

You actually need a multiset implementation. Although there is no multiset out of the box in BCL, there are some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597691/are-there-any-implementations-of-multiset-for-net) and in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183685/c-sharp-set-collection).

Or you can actually implement one by yourself, it's not so complicated:

```
class Multiset<K> // maybe implement IEnumerable?
{
    Dictionary<K, int> arities = new Dictionary<K, int>();
    ...
    Multiset<K> Except(Multiset<K> other)
    {
        foreach (var k in arities.keys)
        {
            int arity = arities[k];
            if (other.Contains(k))
                arity -= other.Arity(k);
            if (arity > 0)
                result.Add(k, arity);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this: (see oded's post for a linq to msdn)

```
int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 }; 
int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 }; 

IEnumerable<int> aOnlyNumbers = numbersA.Except(numbersB);
```