# Why SortedSet<T>.GetViewBetween isn't O(log N)?

Tags: c#, .net, complexity-theory, sortedset

In .NET 4.0+, a class `SortedSet<T>` has a method called `GetViewBetween(l, r)`, which returns an interface view on a tree part containing all the values between the two specified. Given that `SortedSet<T>` is implemented as a red-black tree, I naturally expect it to run in `O(log N)` time. The similar method in C++ is `std::set::lower_bound/upper_bound`, in Java it's `TreeSet.headSet/tailSet`, and they are logarithmic.

However, that is not true. The following code runs in 32 sec, whereas the equivalent `O(log N)` version of `GetViewBetween` would make this code run in 1-2 sec.

```cs
var s = new SortedSet<int>();
int n = 100000;
var rand = new Random(1000000007);
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    s.Add(rand.Next());
    if (rand.Next() % 2 == 0) {
        int l = rand.Next(int.MaxValue / 2 - 10);
        int r = l + rand.Next(int.MaxValue / 2 - 10);
        var t = s.GetViewBetween(l, r);
        sum += t.Min;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

I decompiled System.dll using [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and here's what I got:

```cs
public TreeSubSet(SortedSet<T> Underlying, T Min, T Max, bool lowerBoundActive, bool upperBoundActive)
    : base(Underlying.Comparer)
{
    this.underlying = Underlying;
    this.min = Min;
    this.max = Max;
    this.lBoundActive = lowerBoundActive;
    this.uBoundActive = upperBoundActive;
    this.root = this.underlying.FindRange(this.min, this.max, this.lBoundActive, this.uBoundActive);
    this.count = 0;
    this.version = -1;
    this.VersionCheckImpl();
}

internal SortedSet<T>.Node FindRange(T from, T to, bool lowerBoundActive, bool upperBoundActive)
{
  SortedSet<T>.Node node = this.root;
  while (node != null)
  {
    if (lowerBoundActive && this.comparer.Compare(from, node.Item) > 0)
    {
      node = node.Right;
    }
    else
    {
      if (!upperBoundActive || this.comparer.Compare(to, node.Item) >= 0)
        return node;
      node = node.Left;
    }
  }
  return (SortedSet<T>.Node) null;
}

private void VersionCheckImpl()
{
    if (this.version == this.underlying.version)
      return;
    this.root = this.underlying.FindRange(this.min, this.max, this.lBoundActive, this.uBoundActive);
    this.version = this.underlying.version;
    this.count = 0;
    base.InOrderTreeWalk((TreeWalkPredicate<T>) (n =>
    {
      SortedSet<T>.TreeSubSet temp_31 = this;
      int temp_34 = temp_31.count + 1;
      temp_31.count = temp_34;
      return true;
    }));
}
```

So, `FindRange` is obviously `O(log N)`, but after that we call `VersionCheckImpl`... which does a linear-time traversal of the found subtree only for recounting its nodes!

1. Why would you need to do that traversal all the time?
2. Why .NET does not contain a `O(log N)` method for splitting a tree based on key, like C++ or Java? It is *really* helpful in lots of situations.

Comment: Well, you are right, it is VersionCheckImpl() that ruins it.  The check is quite sacred in .NET collection classes, I can't think of a better way.  You'll get O(log n) as long as you *use* the subset, with checking in place, creating it is however O(n).  You can post to connect.microsoft.com to point this out and get a view from the insiders.  Odds are however high that they'll close it as "By design".

Comment: What an outrageous blunder in the BCL. The GetRange method is supposed to be more efficient than a linear filter!

Comment: @Hans For my curiosity, what is the point of `VersionCheckImpl`?

Comment: It is a tragic consequence of the requirement that [`SortedSet<T>.Count` be O(1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382345.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondChen What's wrong with Java approach? Whatever their implementation is, `GetViewBetween` is derivable in logarithmic time from 2 calls of `headSet` and `tailSet`. All other methods retain consistency, and `Count` retrieval is still constant-time.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the Java approach. (Though I see no requirement that Collection.size be O(1) [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size()).)

Comment: I just want to point out that it isn't quite as bad as linear filter. If I understand the code correctly, only the range is linearly traversed not the whole set.

Comment: That `TreeSubSet` code is just horrible. The constructor calls `FindRange` twice for no good reason. As @hwiechers said, the O(n) traversal is only based on the subset. Still 3 times as many traversals as needed...

Comment: Checking in from 2017 here, the dotnet core implementation of SortedSet<T>.GetViewBetween(...) is a O(log(n)) implementation. Ofc. plus the elements you need to extract.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## about the `version` field

### UPDATE1:

In my memory, a lot of (maybe all?) collections in BCL have the field `version`.

#### First, about `foreach`:

according to this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(v=vs.80).aspx)

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each element in an array or an object collection. The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the desired information, but should not be used to change the contents of the collection to avoid unpredictable side effects.

In many other collections, `version` is protected the data is not modified during the `foreach`

For example, `HashTable`'s `MoveNext()`:

```
public virtual bool MoveNext()
{
    if (this.version != this.hashtable.version)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion"));
    }
    //..........
}
```

But in the `SortedSet<T>`'s `MoveNext()` method:

```
public bool MoveNext()
{
    this.tree.VersionCheck();
    if (this.version != this.tree.version)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
    }       
    //....
}
```

### UPDATE2：

But the O(N) loop maybe not only for `version` but also for the `Count` property.

Because the [MSDN of GetViewBetween](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381801.aspx) said:

> This method returns a view of the range of elements that fall between lowerValue and upperValue, as defined by the comparer .... **You can make changes in both the view and in the underlying SortedSet(Of T)**.

So for every update it should be sync the `count` field (key and value are already same). To make sure the `Count` is correct

There were two policies to reach the target:

1. Microsoft's
2. Mono's

First, MS's, in their code, they sacrifice the `GetViewBetween()`'s performance and win the `Count` property's performance.

`VersionCheckImpl()` is one way to sync the `Count` property.

Second, Mono. In mono's code,`GetViewBetween()` is faster, but in their `GetCount()`method:

```
internal override int GetCount ()
{
    int count = 0;
    using (var e = set.tree.GetSuffixEnumerator (lower)) {
        while (e.MoveNext () && set.helper.Compare (upper, e.Current) >= 0)
            ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

It is always an O(N) operation!

Comment: Wouldn't augmenting each tree node with a 'subtree count' make much more sense?  I've built a Red Black tree this way with little extra effort.  The count value is updated on insertion and removal, (including any affected ancestor nodes).  This approach provides O(log n) sorted indexing into the tree, eg tree[0] returns the smallest node, tree[tree.Count-1] returns the largest. I didn't provide a 'view' concept however, so maybe this complicates it?

Answer (score 14):

In case somebody else like me comes back 10 years after the question has been asked.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/fae7ee8e7e3aa7f86836318a10ed676641e813ad/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedSet.TreeSubSet.cs#L38
Here is the link to TreeSubSet implementation, and seems that the call to VersionCheckImpl() has been removed.

So I guess now you can do :

```
SortedSet<int> ss = new();
ss.Add(1);
ss.Add(2);
//ss.Add(3);
ss.Add(4);
ss.Add(5);
ss.Add(6);
var four = ss.GetViewBetween(3, ss.Max()).First();
```

in O(logn)