# C# structure like std::set that supports lower_bound

Tags: c#, c++, dictionary, lower-bound

I need a built-in datastructure in `C#` that has functionality similar to `std::set` (or `std::map`) in c++. What is important to me is that the structure should be sorted(thus `Dictionary` will not do here) and has a method similar to `lower_bound`(i.e. return first element with value at least `v`). I will also need to insert and delete elements from the structure. If possible I need these operations to have complexity `O(log(n))`. Could you please point me to the appropriate datastructure in `C#`?

Comment: @Mankarse by the way the question is not exactly duplicate because it assumes one has already heard of SortedSet, while I only heard of it as a result of this question

Comment: I agree, but I think that the questions are similar enough that their answers could be merged (as any answer to one will naturally answer the other).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are looking for [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) in terms of a similar data structure to std::set.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee906600.aspx) goes into its performance characteristics.

A `lower_bound` functionality seems to be possible using [SortedSet.GetViewBetween](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381801.aspx) but has a worse complexity than the desired O(log(n)) according to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850975/why-sortedsett-getviewbetween-isnt-olog-n).

Comment: could you please point me to a way to achieve lower_bound like functionality with it?

Comment: Sorry, i misread the functionality of lower_bound in that context. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850975/why-sortedsett-getviewbetween-isnt-olog-n seems to be related to what you are trying to to (but does not look to promising in terms of getting the functionality within the BCL in O(log(n))).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev use .GetViewBetween() on the SortedSet, or the .First() methond (.First() is a linq extension)

Comment: @SimonOpelt take a look at the question linked to as duplicate by Mankrese seems a lower bound can be done using a binary search on the keys.

Comment: @nos what would be the complexity of this method?

Comment: Please include the relevant information in the actual answer and only use links to back up your answer.

Comment: damn, only from C# 4 :'(

Comment: `GetViewBetween` is indeed really good. .NET doesn't expose the lower/upper bound as iterators directly, but as a subtree of the whole tree. This model is in line with Java's `SortedMap` and `TreeMap`. So no problem here. As to the issue `GetViewBetween` being O(n), it's really tragic. But as a comment in your link points out, Mono & .NET core does have O(logn) implementation for this method.