# .NET equivalent of Java's TreeSet.floor & TreeSet.ceiling

Tags: c#, .net, binary-search-tree

As an example, there's a Binary Search Tree which holds a range of values. Before adding a new value, I need to check if it already contains it's 'almost duplicate'. I have Java solution which simply performs floor and ceiling and further condition to do the job.

**JAVA**: Given a `TreeSet`, `floor()` returns the greatest element in this set less than or equal to the given element; `ceiling()` returns the least element in this set greater than or equal to the given element

```
TreeSet<Long> set = new TreeSet<>();

long l = (long)1;  // anything
Long floor = set.floor(l);
Long ceil = set.ceiling(l);
```

**C#**: Closest data structure seems to be `SortedSet<>`. Could anyone advise the best way to get floor and ceil results for an input value?

```
SortedSet<long> set = new SortedSet<long>();
```

Comment: Probably `Math.Floor` and `Math.Ceiling`. What is `l` though?

Comment: @SeM, I need floor and ceiling methods that operate on BST range

Comment: This is needed so badly in the .Net. You can't implement a wide range of algorithms without writing your own data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this. In Linq there is LastOrDefault method:

```
var floor = sortedSet.LastOrDefault(i => i < num);
// num is the number whose floor is to be calculated
if (! (floor < sortedSet.ElementAt(0)))
{
  // we have a floor
}
else
 // nothing is smaller in the set
{
}
```

Comment: This won't have the nice logarithmic time complexity of Java solution, right? It's just a linear search.

Comment: Yes agreed. I think search is binary with O(n).. sortedset in c# vs treeset in java will make a good SO question

Answer (score 2):

The above, as mentioned, is not the answer since this is a tree we expect logarithmic times. Java's floor and ceiling methods are logarithmic. GetViewBetween is logarigmic and so are Max and Min, so:

floor for `SortedSet<long>`:
`sortedSet.GetViewBetween(long.MinValue, num).Max`

ceiling for `SortedSet<long>`: 
`sortedSet.GetViewBetween(num, long.MaxValue).Min`

Comment: As GetViewBetween() method returns SortedSet, which contains Count property that requires O(N) time to configure, this method does not achieve logarithmic time complexity.

Comment: Unfortunately GetViewBetween() is O(N)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850975/why-sortedsett-getviewbetween-isnt-olog-n

Comment: Though GetViewBetween() might be O(logN) according to some comments, isn't the code itself wrong? `sortedSet.GetViewBetween(num, long.MaxValue).Min` is `num` itself.

Comment: @chuang not if `num` is not in `sortedSet`. The code looks correct to me. And some comments here say that dotnet core's `GetViewBetween` is `O(logN)` (agreeing with you, just didn't see such comments on this question): https://stackoverflow.com/q/9850975/2850543