# What is the .net equivalent of a java hashbag collection

Tags: java, .net, hash, bag

What is the .net equivalent of a java hashbag collection, a collection that stores like items only once but also stores the number of occurrences of the items?

Comment: I don't think there is a .net equivalent.

Comment: Implementing it using a `Dictionary<T, int>` shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Thanks, implementing it using `Dictionary<T, int>` wasn't too hard and works well for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

See also: [Duplicate keys in .NET dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146204/duplicate-keys-in-net-dictionaries/146218#146218)  Another common name for bag is multiset, see also: [Are there any implementations of multiset for .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597691/are-there-any-implementations-of-multiset-for-net)

Via those links I found the Wintellect's Power Collections [bag](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/PowerCollections/Bag.cs) implementation.  From its source:

```
Bag<T> is a collection that contains items of type T. 
Unlike a Set, duplicate items (items that compare equal to each other) are allowed in an
Bag.
```

Not a .net user myself so I don't know if this library is too old to be useful.  Hopefully it helps!