# delete same lines from text file by c#

Tags: c#, text-files

how to delete same lines in file .txt but keep one of them using c# ?

Comment: Restate your question please, I wasn't able to understand it >_< sorry.

Comment: example I have 5 lines in text file three of them is "he is going to school" 
I want to delete two and keep one of them but the lines distributed in text 
like :
It is a cat 
he is going to school
I will take my book
he is going to school
he is going to school

Comment: Sounds like a dedupe? How do you know which one of the lines you want to keep? Do you just keep the first instance?

Answer (score 10):

Read line by line.  Add the line to a HashSet, and Add returns true, print the line to the output.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. One could be to use some version of a Set. Look at [C# Set collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183685/c-set-collection) for this.

If all the same lines are after one another, you could just iterate through and see if the line matches the last line. If it does, discard it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would look something like this:

1. For each line in the input file.
2. If the current line is not the same
   as the previous line, write it to
   the output file.
3. Set the current line equal to the
   previous line.

This assumes that duplicate lines are adjacent. If they are not adjacent, you will have to sort the file first.

Comment: The OP clarified in a comment that they're not adjacent.