# C# Array, How to make data in an array distinct from each other?

Tags: c#, arrays, distinct-values

C# Array, How to make data in an array distinct from each other?
For example

```
string[] a = {"a","b","a","c","b","b","c","a"};
```

how to get

```
string[]b = {"a","b","c"}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Easiest way is the LINQ `Distinct()` command :

```
var b = a.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: Distinct returns an IEnumerable<T>. You need the the ToArray() to cast it to an array.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to consider using a [Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183685/c-set-collection) instead of an array. Sets can't contain duplicates so adding the second "a" would have no effect. That way your collection of characters will always contain no duplicates and you won't have to do any post processing on it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = new HashSet<string> { };
list.Add("a");
list.Add("a");

var countItems = list.Count(); //in this case countItems=1
```

Answer (score 1):

An array, which you start with, is `IEnumerable<T>`. `IEnumerable<T>` has a `Distinct()` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) which can be used to manipulate the list into its distinct values

```
var distinctList = list.Distinct();
```

Finally,`IEnumerable<T>` has a `ToArray()` method:

```
var b = distinctList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using c# Dictionary is the better way and I can sort by value using [LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-dictionary-by-value)