# Which data structure/class I can use to represent one-to-many relation?

Tags: c#, data-structures, one-to-many

I am trying to write a program that would use a data structure/class that will hold multiple data entries for one key - this will be somehow similar to Dictionary but it's not one to one but one to many relation. I am trying to think of a class that I can use but I cannot figure anything out.

For instance how it may look like:

I have a parameter xValue and 3 different values in different files so i would have :

```
xValue, <1.txt, 1>
xValue, <2.txt, 2>
xValue, <3.txt, 3>
```

Any ideas ?

**EDIT:**
I have figured this out - After all I can use

`Dictionary< string , Dictionary<..., ... > >`

, can't I ?

Comment: indeed, you can use nested dictionaries, but if you don't need to know from which file does the `xValue` come, you can just take a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there is no multiset in .NET natively, I would go for

```
Dictionary<Key, HashSet<XValue>>
```

in your case.

If you are ok with using 3rd-party containers, you can look up the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183685/c-sharp-set-collection), e.g., [Wintellect PowerCollections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need modify this collection after initialization and just need to do search, you can leverage built in `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` class, but really this would be tricky and useful in rare cases when you already have `IEnumerable<>` instances and would flatten it to lookup data structure, anyway this is pretty useful to keep in mind that .NET provides such intersting class.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb460184.aspx)

> Represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values. A
>   `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` resembles a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. The
>   difference is that a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` maps keys to single
>   values, whereas a `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` maps keys to collections of
>   values.

You can not instantiate it explicitly and just can get instance of lookup using LINQ `ToLookup()` method. There are major restrictions so you can use this class as lookup data structure - doing search.

> There is no public constructor to create a new instance of a
>   Lookup. Additionally, Lookup objects
>   are immutable, that is, you cannot add or remove elements or keys from
>   a Lookup object after it has been created.