# Data structures used for Redis

Tags: c#, nosql, redis

I'm trying to answer these questions about dataType in redis as it becomes so confusing for me.

1. if I want to store a string data or List<string> data in redis ,what would be the real format of data stored in Redis ?
2. What would be considered as Set in Redis ? what kind of data structure in c# consider as Set and can be stored there?
3. What's is different between redisClient.Set() and redisClient.SAdd() from IRedisNativeClient Interface in ServiceStack and for what kind of dataType I should use them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 - A string data differs from a List, a string is a list of char a List is a list of strings. If you want to store strings use Redis "STRING" (or "HASH", if you want an **HASHMAP**), if you want to store a list of strings use a Redis LIST.

2 - [**You are looking for HashSet.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183685/c-sharp-set-collection)

3 - See [**set**](http://redis.io/commands/set) and [**sadd**](http://redis.io/commands/sadd):

```
void Set(string key, byte[] value); // (STRING op) set a string "value" at the key "key".
void SAdd(string setId, byte[] value); // (SET op) add a "value" into the set "setId".
```