# Is there a set type in .NET 2.0?

Tags: .net, generics, .net-2.0, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a “Set” data structure in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458/is-there-a-set-data-structure-in-net)

**Duplicate:** this is a duplicate of "[Is there a “Set” data structure in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458/is-there-a-set-data-structure-in-net)". Please close it as a duplicate and address any further answers to the earlier question.

Is there a generic collection analogous to the STL `set<T>` template in the .NET framework?

If not, how would you implement a non-ordered collection of unique strings? I suppose I could use `Dictionary<string, int>` and just use the keys, but that feels kind of smelly.

EDIT: sorry, I should have specified that this is for .NET 2.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until .NET3.5, no (don't ask me why it took them so long to get these fundamentals added. (There's still no heap class, afaik. The .NET collection classes are surprisingly lackluster).

In 3.5, you have `HashSet<T>`. It's more like the TR1 `unordered_set` than `std::set` though, in that it's unordered, where `std::set` uses a tree structure internally.

Of course there are several third-party libraries offering to fix these shortcomings.

I've looked at [C5](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) (as suggested by Pratik) before, but never used it. But it seems to be pretty good quality, and has a Set class.

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest [The C5 Generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) that has a hash set collection class among many others.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a .NET 2.0 set implementation

Answer (score 1):

[HashSet Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is YES.
Check out the Jeff Richter's amazing [Power Collections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections) library for some of the most commonly used STL equivalent collection types for .NET. On an unrelated note he also has a [Power Threading](http://wintellect.com/PowerThreading.aspx) library

Comment: You beat me!  I deleted my answer pointing at Power Collections.  I second Abhijeet in thinking that Power Collections is the library you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) collection.

Answer (score 0):

Since .net 3.5, there is the [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) which implements a Set. Not sure if it's totally equal to C++'s set though.